# Rails syntax error - cant' find the reason for it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to achieve the following, by pushing a button on a page the user to get a random item from the database which will be showed, but will have  an attribute editable. The problem I hit into, is the following I don't know how to pass an random id(valid in the database), to be rendered in my partial, but still to be able to update the specific attribute.

Problem from the title:

```
  SyntaxError in Tasks#main
  Showing /home/bogdan/ex/bored/app/views/tasks/main.html.erb where line #1 raised:
/home/bogdan/ex/bored/app/views/tasks/main.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...uffer.append=  form_for (:task, :url => {:action =>'rand_tas...
...                               ^
/home/bogdan/ex/bored/app/views/tasks/main.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
...url => {:action =>'rand_task'}) do |f|@output_buffer.safe_co...
...                               ^
../app/views/tasks/main.html.erb:8: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end 
Extracted source (around line #1):
1: <%= form_for (:task, :url => {:action =>'rand_task'}) do |f|%>
2:     <%= render(:partial => "rand_show", :locals => {:f => f}) %></p> 
3: <%end%>
4: 
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/tasks/main.html.erb
```

I was trying to pass the rand_task output object to the _rand_show.html.erb  and afterwartds call a new editable form only for the attr i'm intressted in by the `id`

form:

```
<%= form_for(@task = Task.new) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, :disabled=>true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :category, :disabled=>true %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

random method:

```
def rand_task
    if params[:id] == 'random'
      @task = Task.order('RANDOM()').first
    else
      @task = Task.order('RANDOM()').first // if not  i get a nill related error.
    end 
  end
```

Please help why do i get the above mentioned error? IS the concept i'm thinking about wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= form_for (:task, :url => {:action =>'rand_task'}) do |f| %>
            ^
```

The problem is the space between `form_for` and `(`. If you remove the space it should work.